# Receiving through ObjectInputStream() without having the class

Tags: java, sockets, deserialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to make a server that receives an object that implements an interface X sent by a Client through the ObjectInputStream ().

Better Explain:
I want to make the Server receives the Object through an interface without actually having the Class on Server side.

Because of ObjectInputStream () deserialize the Object, the class must necessarily exist on the server side, if does not, occur ClassNotFoundException ().

Is there any other way to pass an Object through a Socket without necessarily having the Class of him on the other side? I'm searching different ways that do the same ObjectInputStream, but without having the Class on Server side. If thre's no way of do that, I will must upload the Class all the time on the Server, so the ObjectInputStream can deserialize and dont throws ClassNotFoundException.

Thanks.

Comment: An instance of what class would you like to get as the result of this deserialization?

Comment: the class should be in server side too

Comment: It's a Custom Class that I want do deserialize on the Server Side. I Know that I must have the Class on the Server Side. I'm searching a way to do this without having the Class. Like ObjectInputStream , but without having the class. Sorry if its not clear on the ask. I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to instantiate the object, you can keep it in a byte[] buffer. To instantiate it, you need to do it like RMI: provide a remote class loader by the sender.

But typically solutions using a different serialisation mechanism are better for that case. Think Protobuf, JSON or similiar.

Comment: Thanks Eckes, I will study that Protobuf and see how it can help me to do that. As quicly I read, I think it's the better approach on what I want to do.